# Torch mv behavior not understandable

Tags: pytorch

The following screenshots show that torch.mv is unusable in a situation that obviously seem to be correct... how is this possible, any idea what can be the problem?

[image]

[image]

this first image shows the correct situation, where the vector has 10 rows for a matrix of 10 columns, but I showed the other also just in case. Also swapping w.mv(x) for x.mv(w)  does not make a difference.

[image]

However, the @ operator works... the thing is that for my own reasons I want to use mv, so I would like to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mv.html):

> *torch.mv(input, vec, *, out=None) → Tensor*
> If input is a (n×m) tensor, vec is a 1-D tensor of size m, out will be 1-D of size n.

The `x` here should be 1-D, but in your case it's 10x1 (2D). You can remove extra dimension (or create a single dimension `x`)

```
>>> w.mv(x.squeeze())
 
tensor([ 0.1432, -2.0639, -2.1871, -1.8837,  0.7333, -0.4000,  0.4023, -1.1318,
         0.0423, -1.2136])

>>> w @ x
 
tensor([[ 0.1432],
        [-2.0639],
        [-2.1871],
        [-1.8837],
        [ 0.7333],
        [-0.4000],
        [ 0.4023],
        [-1.1318],
        [ 0.0423],
        [-1.2136]])
```